# Is it OK to let invalid arguments slip to another method?

Tags: .net, exception-handling

For example lets take this method:

```cs
public List<string[]> ReadAll(int listCapacity)
{
    List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>(listCapacity);

    while (Read())
    {
        list.Add(GetCurrentRow());
    }

    return list;
}
```

If `listCapacity` is less than zero, an `ArgumentException` will be thrown by the constructor of `List<T>`. Does it make sense to double check this? Passing the argument to `List<T>` immediately seems careless, but checking it seems silly because `List<T>` will definitely check it.

Important note: the code snippet is not just a copy-paste method, its part of a full utility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aside [memory allocation reason](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/246897/6605) (which, by the way, looks like premature optimization to me), there are other elements in favor of catching invalid arguments as soon as possible:

### Stack trace

When an exception occurs, you expect the few last lines to show you the location of a mistake. Having to search from bottom to top of the stack to find the culprit will waste your time later, during debug, when you specifically won't have time.

Being sloppy about input validation and letting called methods handle that again and again will mean that **the stack trace will be larger than it should be**. If you know that `ReadAll` cannot accept a negative capacity, why adding a line to stack trace, instead of throwing an exception right now in order to make the debugging easy?

### Readability

Your code is expected to be **self-documenting**. I can only know your method doesn't accept negative values if I inspect the method closely. This is OK if I'm about to modify the method; this is not OK if I simply want to *use* the method, and don't really care *how* is it implemented.

And no, I can't rely on documentation, since it's *always* incomplete and obsolete.

Validating the inputs right at the top of the method would help readability: it would be clear that I can't use negative values, and I would avoid wasting additional time:

- Inspecting the body of the method,
- Inspecting every method in the code base this method calls,
- Reading MSDN for every .NET Framework method this method calls.

### Code contracts

Since you tagged your question [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and your code looks like C#, I can't avoid talking about code contracts. If you have used code contracts, you would be forced to add a `Contract.Requires` anyway, otherwise the static checker will complain that nothing guarantees that the list constructor will be called with valid arguments.

That's also the **benefit of code contracts: they force you to handle invalid inputs at the top of the stack**, so when the input is invalid, you stop right now, instead of calling dozens of other methods before encountering an exception.

Comment: The additional check is only effective if an invalid argument is passed which should be uncommon, yet it requires some instructions. So I doubt that this has anything to do with optimization. I think you are right concerning debugging. It sounds plausible to me that any public method has the responsibility the check the arguments that it requires, because nothing implies that it is going to be passed along exclusively, maybe the method has some special treatment for negative values.

Comment: In general, your arguments are good.  However, in this particular example, it doesn't require a rocket scientist to expect that listCapacity be non-negative.  And, if List ever somehow changes to accept a negative capacity, so should your code (probably).

Comment: @user949300: *"it doesn't require a rocket scientist to expect that listCapacity be non-negative"*: it *looks like* it should be non-negative, but only inspection of the method and MSDN confirms that. I stopped counting long ago the cases where, in programming, something obviously looked like something, but actually wasn't.

Comment: @MainMa  Question: every time you allocate or insert into an array, do you check the size or index for >= 0?  I doubt it.  IMO, this case is similar.

Comment: @user949300: actually, yes. In C#, I systematically use code contracts, so the size and the index are always checked. But I see your point.

Comment: @MainMa - wow, you are very thorough, more thorough than most programmers.  Hope you get paid by lines of code!  :-)  For the record, I'm upvoting your answer.

Comment: Though I upvoted your answer, I think the "readability" argument is double-edged. Validating the input at the beginning is still something in the method body, it does neither increase or decrease the readability from a user's point of view, maybe from the maintainers point of view (but maybe a maintainer would disagree because he has to look into the code with or without the extra check). Code contracts might help, but they are not widely used. ...

Comment: ... So The only way I know of to increase the readability in a self-documenting way, without adding tons of redundant written docs is to have some good naming for the variable names, maybe some conventions. A name like "listCapacity" should be mostly understood as non-negative (due to the fact most of us will have an expectation about the List class of the .NET framework and the use of the word capacity in that context). Note that a good naming is completely independent of where and how the check for >=0 is done.

Comment: As far as readability, listCapacity is a parameter, and the docs should say something like "used to allocate the List" and, if you are paranoid, "non-negative".  IMO, that is better than a fairly pointless test.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: it depends.  In your example, you should let List throw its exception and let any exception bubble up the chain.

Your example method should not know or care whether the value is invalid, since it's sole purpose is to pass it along to something else.  If you were using the value in ReadAll as something other than an argument to List, you would be correct to test it before use, but you're not.

An invalid argument to your method is not one that will not be understood by a separate utility, it is one that does not make sense to your code.

As a side note, parameters that exist simply to be passed along, should be fairly rare.

Comment: Passing a negative intial list capacity definitely doesn't make sense, whether my external code is qualified to judge that, is a very good question. You have a good point.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: it doesn't make sense to you, but List could be changed so that negative values have meaning -- it could for instance be a flag that changes the way reallocation works.  So that instead of doubling when necessary it only increases it by 50% or conversely by 3x.

Comment: What you're saying is definitely something to be concerned about overall. But I really doubt Microsoft would implement such hack, they would probably provide another overload.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: true, they are much more likely to simple ignore it if it's negative.  Frankly I halfway consider it a bug that it throws an exception now.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, it's not OK. Because even calling the constructor of List means, from the compiller's perspective: memory allocation for the new object, writing references for it in the reference table, accessing other subroutines just to create the new List object, just to have it basically blow up in your face by throwing an exception.

I know it doesn't seem like much with all these available resources on the system, but it's still not something I would do - if I can avoid it with just one extra line of code.

Comment: This hits the nail on the head.

Comment: -1  I think that @MainMa has a much better argument.  Efficiency is definitely NOT the major consideration here.

Comment: I don't think the answer implies that efficiency is a consideration, this is about correctness. @MainMa has a very informative answer which received my upvote, but I prefer this point of view. For example why permit a crash when not `List<T>.ctor()` but `ReadAll()` requires the argument.

Comment: Unlike MainMa, nowhere in this answer is the word "correct" or "contract" or "readability" or similar.  All the terms are about memory, writing to tables, calling other subroutines, etc.  This answer is _all_ about efficiency.

Comment: @user949300 I think you're missing the point. The remarks about runtime mechanisms were explanatory, not judging.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: IMHO user949300 is correct, the reasoning in this answer is completely missing the point - additional use of compiler resources is fully acceptable when the result would be less redundant code - following the reasoning above, we should all do assembly programming. If in this case the code without the additional check is less or more maintainable is debatable (see my comment below MainMa's answer), indeed, but that is not part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Gotta disagree with the [accepted answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/246897/31260).  The argument about allocating memory, etc. is only relevant if this method is called *often* with an illegal argument.

The purpose of checking arguments (programming by contract) and throwing exceptions is primarily to fix bugs during development.  During development, efficiency is not an issue.  Combined with unit tests, this should assure that `ReadAll()` is *not* called with a negative argument.  Or at least only called rarely in a case you didn't test.

So, with proper development and testing, efficiency will never be an issue.  Letting the check slip one or two levels is fine.  Though you may want to add a comment.

**EDIT #1 added**

Let's make the example slightly different.  The function returns the result as an array:

`public string[] ReadAll(int maxCapacity) {...}`

Would you check for maxCapacity>= 0 in your code?  Unlikely.  IMO, this case of using a List is close enough to an Array that checking the initialCapacity is overkill.

**EDIT #2 Added**

There are many times where it is completely unreasonable to check an incoming argument yourself.  For example, say that there is an XML String coming in.  Your method looks something like this: (pseudo-Java-like code, nor am I claiming that this is a good design)

```
public double getFooBarFraction(String xml) throws AllKindsOfExceptions {
   Document doc = DOMParser.getInstance().parse(xml);
   return Double.parseDouble(doc.getElement("Foo")
                                .getElement("Bar")
                                .getAttribute("fraction"));
}
```

1. Are you going to validate the XML yourself, or let the utility
   DOMParser do that?
2. Are you going to look for elements and attributes
   yourself, or let Document do that?
3. Are you going to test that count
   can be parsed to an double, or let Double do that?

The answer is almost certainly "no" to *all* of the questions.  Now, you probably should wrap the calls in try/catch blocks for better error handling, but you still let the utility create the original exception.

In rereading the other answers, they do say "where it's easy to test" etc.  I guess if you can do the test in one or two lines of code, consider doing it.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but you have no way of knowing that the behavior of the List class will remain unaltered forever. It may someday be that it won't throw an exception anymore, so what happens then with your (hopefully, already in production) code then if you depend on this behavior?

Comment: I'm still indecisive in this matter, but @Thyamarkos had a very good point. Favoring succesful initialization is logical and it is a good practise, even if its regarding a framework component such as `List<T>`.

Comment: @Thyamarkos If, somehow, List changes and allows a negative number of elements (unlikely I know!), your code should probably change to allow that.  A more realistic scenario might be an upper limit on a List or Map or whatever.  If the default upper limit increases in .NET version 34.0, because they come up with a better algorithm or memory is cheaper, your code should, most likely, accept that higher limit.

Comment: @user949300 - The current implementation of `List<T>` has no upper limit, but unlike negative values, such limit is not reliable at all since the limit will be an arbitrary power of 2 between 0 and `int.MaxValue`. Prior to doing an operation, there is no way to predict a `OutOfMemoryException` either, so I guess letting this slip could be justified in that sense.

Comment: Even if someday `List` will be changed to accept 0 for is capacity, `ReadAll` will still work as expected - it'll create a list with the initial capacity of `listCapacity` and read to it. It seems like the sole reason for `ReadAll` to not accept 0 is because `List`'s c'tor doesn't accept it - so what's the point in doing extra work just to make sure that even if `List`'s c'tor will supports 0 `ReadAll` still won't accept it?

Comment: @Thyamarkos: if the behaviour of the .NET framework `List` class would be changed by Microsoft in such a way, that would break compatibility for hundred thousands of programs - so I guess we can safely assume they will not change that.

Comment: @Doc Brown: I'm not saying they will, I'm just saying it could happen. I think it's safe to say that, no matter the reason, a practice such as the one described in the original question is unsafe and undesired in an application - my personal background is heavily on the PHP side, where the rule of thumb is to double-check and triple-check anything, since the kind of unwelcomed behavior I've detailed in my answer is much more likely to show up due to the weakly-typed nature of the language and the massive changes in the interpreter from one version to another.